# Stuck on fully deleting eset smart secuiraty

Tags: windows-10

I am not sure if I had to ask it here but I cannot find any other sites to ask.

I installed ESET smart Security on my computer but I didn't like the trial version. Thats why I deleted it with control panel but it isn't fully deleted, it creates alot of issues, it fill's 90% of my CPU usage.

how can I delete it?

I am using widows10-enterprise 64bit

Comment: Chances are that ESET produces this problem after some major Win10 upgrades. Removing it with the removal tool (mentioned below), then doing a clean reinstall of ESET, usually solves this issue. In this process, you should upgrade to the latest ESET version. Simply reinstalling on top of a broken installation usually doesn't fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESET Uninstaller is a tool used to completely uninstall any ESET product in case of a unsuccessful uninstallation or remaining files resisting to be deleted. The tool can be used as in a 32-bit machine as a 64-bit machine.

--NOTE-- If you mind your Network settings, then it's advisable to create a backup files of your settings and network drivers. As ESET team says...

> Before running the Uninstaller Tool: Open an administrative command prompt and enter the following command to back up your network adapter settings:
>
> `netsh -c interface dump > c:\NetworkSettings.txt`
>
> After uninstallation is complete: Reinstall your network adapter drivers if necessary and then open an administrative command prompt and enter the following command to restore your network adapter settings:
>
> `netsh -f C:\NetworkSettings.txt`

1. Download the tool from [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/eset-uninstaller/) (It's advisable to place the tool in an easy-access folder, such as the Desktop).
2. Go into Safe Mode (a quick way is clicking the Restart button in the Start menu while holding the Shift key). Other way to do this is opening Run dialog > msconfig > Boot tab > and checking the "Safe Mode" option. Click Accept to restart your computer.
3. Once in Safe Mode, run the tool, a command-prompt based interface will be shown. Press "y" to start the process. Next, the program will show you all the detected ESET products, type the number of the product you want to delete and press Enter.

[image: Uninstallation process]
You'll be asked again to confirm the uninstallation, press "y" to confirm.

Now you have to let the machine complete the work: once completed, a "Press any key to continue..." message will appear (a log file is generated in the desktop). All you have to do now is to restart your computer.

--NOTE 2-- If you used msconfig to enable Safe Mode, access msconfig again to disable the Safe Mode check, else, your computer will start again in Safe Mode.

Comment: Excuse me how can I Open an administrative command prompt?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Open the Start Menu and type cmd , then right click > Run as administrator.